# knockout.js nested foreach referencing each other

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm trying to fill in the rows and cells of my table like the following:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: {data: rows, as: 'row'}">
    <tr data-bind="foreach: {data: row, as: 'cell'}">
        <td data-bind="text: cell"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

with this as my rows var:

```
self.rows = ko.observableArray([
            [
                ['Test', '10', '100', '98', '10', '15']
            ],
            [
                ['Test2', '10', '100', '98', '10', '20']
            ]
]);
```

This fills in the correct number of rows, but only the first TD is populated with the entire contents of the array.

results in:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: {data: rows, as: 'row'}">
    <tr data-bind="foreach: {data: row, as: 'cell'}">
        <td data-bind="text: cell">Test,10,100,98,10,15</td>
    </tr>

    <tr data-bind="foreach: {data: row, as: 'cell'}">
        <td data-bind="text: cell">Test2,10,100,98,10,20</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have three levels of arrays and you're only iterating two levels deep. If you change your `rows` data to nest only two levels deep, it should work as expected:

```
self.rows = ko.observableArray([
    [
        'Test', '10', '100', '98', '10', '15'
    ],
    [
        'Test2', '10', '100', '98', '10', '20'
    ]
]);
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Zj2qN/

Answer (score 1):

You have a 3rd level array. Are you sure you need that?

If so you to need nest one more foreach binding.

I dont think so, I think you want your array look this way:

```
self.rows = ko.observableArray([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]);
```